# PHP predict a redirect/change of URL on another website?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, file-get-contents

Is it possible to handle a redirection from another website and be able to get the new URL the other website directs to?

I'm trying to use `file_get_contents` on another website and make the script run every day or so, however, the URL I am getting contents from has a hash code in it which is changing every day.

For instance: `http://website.com/data/kkLs31` being the page I am getting contents from, the `kkLs31` will change daily to a completey different code, but when you visit the old link even if it has changed, their server will just redirect you to the new "code" no matter what you put in your browser.

So I need to handle when they redirect you to the new code, get the new code and pass it on my server so I can always get contents from them.

I'm not sure if this is even possible at all but I figured there should be something I could do.

If this makes no sense I am happy to elaborate.

Comment: Just use `cURL` instead of `file_get_contents()` since it can follow redirects.

Comment: Which setopt would I use and how would I configure it to manage the redirect? I am not so good with this.

Comment: The documentation is completely and precise. I suggest you take a look at it: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: `file_gent_contents()` should follow redirects, did you try to use it on the original link? BTW CURL gives you much more control over your request. Also, are you sure the redirect is made via HTTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CURL by using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);`

```
$ch =   curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://website.com/data/kkLs31');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // your answer will be in the header
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a =    curl_exec($ch);
```

Next you can get the url with something like:

```
preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!", $a, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
```

*OR*

Use a simple `var_dump($a)` to find your answer

*NOTE:

See how `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set to false, this is because true would keep forwarding you. False does not forward you but does give you the url that it wants you to forward to.*

Comment: This is giving me `HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect Server: nginx/1.7.12 Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2015 11:26:47 GMT Content-Type: text/plain Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=20 Location: https:/website.com/data/Jlek23 P3P: CP="NON DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR STP STA" Vary: User-Agent Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains DIS-CacheStatus: MISS`

Comment: So that's good, see the location: `Location: https:/website.com/data/Jlek23`
Give me some time to update my question

Comment: Thanks so much! So essentially I have to run curl twice in the same script, once to get the URL and again so I can do whatever with my script with the URL?

Comment: Welcome, and sure you can :-)